# How to map columns From one DataFrame onto another based on a column values between the two?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

Basically, I just want map values from one dataframe to another based on some common column, ('ID' + 'Key')

df1:

```
ID    Name 

1     Sam
2     Ryan
4     Sam
16    Brian
7     Tom
8     Gemma
9     Steve
11    Sarah
```

df1:

```
Key   PPID    M

1     22      MM
2     23      R
4     25      MM
16    27      RR
7     21      RR
8     11      R
0     13      SS
11    14      RR
```

new df:

```
ID     PPID    M

Sam    22      MM
Ryan   23      R
Sam    25      MM
Brian  27      RR
Tom    21      RR
Gemma  11      R
0      13      SS
Sarah  14      RR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df1.Key.replace(dict(zip(df.ID,df.Name)),inplace=True)
df1
     Key  PPID   M
0    Sam    22  MM
1   Ryan    23   R
2    Sam    25  MM
3  Brian    27  RR
4    Tom    21  RR
5  Gemma    11   R
6      0    13  SS
7  Sarah    14  RR
```

Comment: Thanks! What do 'dict' and 'zip' mean?

Comment: @Sam create the dict with data frame , then we using replace , since replace accept data type dict

Comment: @Sam if this answer was useful to you, please consider upvoting it in addition to choosing it as the accepted answer.  Also, `dict` and `zip` are core pieces of Python and you SHOULD learn them.  Consider going through a [python tutorial](https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F).